# detached entity passed to persist, many to many JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, many-to-one

Hi i'm trying to create a new request and link it with a already created person on db, but i'm getting a error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TG_REQUEST")
public class TgRequest {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TG_REQUEST", sequenceName = "S_TG_REQUEST", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "TG_REQUEST")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long idRequest;

  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tgRequest", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<TgRequestPerson> tgRequestPersons = new HashSet<>();


    public TgRequest() {

    }

    public void addTgRequestPerson(TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson) {

        tgRequestPersons.add(tgRequestPerson);
        tgRequestPerson.setTgRequest(this);
    }

    public void removeTgRequestPerson(TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson) {


        this.tgRequestPersons.remove(tgRequestPerson);
        tgRequestPerson.setTgRequest(null);
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "TG_PERSON")
public class TgPerson {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TG_PERSON", sequenceName = "S_TG_PERSON", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "TG_PERSON")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long idPerson;

 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tgPerson")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<TgRequestPerson> tgRequestPersons = new HashSet<>();

    public TgPerson() {

    }

    public void addTgRequestPerson(TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson) {

        tgRequestPersons.add(tgRequestPerson);
        tgRequestPerson.setTgPerson(this);
    }

    public void removeTgRequestPerson(TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson) {

        this.tgRequestPersons.remove(tgRequestPerson);
        tgRequestPerson.setTgPerson(null);
    }


}



@Entity
@Table(name = "TG_REQUEST_PERSON")
public class TgRequestPerson {


    @EmbeddedId
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private TgRequestPersonKey idRequestPerson;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idRequest")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_REQUEST")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private TgRequest tgRequest;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("idPerson")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private TgPerson tgPerson;


    public TgRequestPerson() {

    }

}



@Embeddable
public class TgRequestPersonKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID_REQUEST")
    private Long idRequest;

    @Column(name = "ID_PERSON")
    private Long idPerson;

    public TgRequestPersonKey() {

    }

    public Long getIdRequest() {
        return idRequest;
    }

    public void setIdRequest(Long idRequest) {
        this.idRequest = idRequest;
    }

    public Long getIdPerson() {
        return idPerson;
    }

    public void setIdPerson(Long idPerson) {
        this.idPerson = idPerson;
    }
}
```

### code to save (new request link to an existing person on db):

```
TgRequest tgRequest = new TgRequest();

Long idPerson = 1; //Person already exists on db, with id = 1

TgPerson tgPerson = new TgPerson();
tgPerson.setIdPerson(idPerson)

TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson = new TgRequestPerson();
TgRequestPersonKey tgRequestPersonKey = new TgRequestPersonKey();
tgRequestPersonKey.setIdRequest(tgRequest.getIdRequest());
tgRequestPersonKey.setIdPerson(idPerson);
tgRequest.addTgRequestPerson(tgRequestPerson);
tgPerson.addTgRequestPerson(tgRequestPerson);
tgRequestPerson.setIdRequestPerson(tgRequestPersonKey);


requestRepository.save(tgRequest);
```

What i'm specting

insert tgRequest; --> generates a new id

insert tgRequestPerson (idRequest = new created, idPerson = 1)
(link the new created request with an already person on db)

it fails.

### error

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: TgPerson
```

### code to update (link a created request with a created person)

```
TgRequest tgRequest = requestRepository.findByIdRequest(1); //Request already exists
Long idPerson = 1; //Person already exists on db, with id = 1,

TgPerson tgPerson = new TgPerson();
tgPerson.setIdPerson(idPerson)

TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson = new TgRequestPerson();
TgRequestPersonKey tgRequestPersonKey = new TgRequestPersonKey();
tgRequestPersonKey.setIdRequest(tgRequest.getIdRequest());
tgRequestPersonKey.setIdPerson(idPerson);
tgRequest.addTgRequestPerson(tgRequestPerson);
tgPerson.addTgRequestPerson(tgRequestPerson);
tgRequestPerson.setIdRequestPerson(tgRequestPersonKey);


requestRepository.save(tgRequest);
```

Expecting

insert tgRequestPerson (idRequest = 1, idPerson = 1) it works!

So, how can i make the save code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `getOne` which uses `entityManager.getReference` behind the scenes, to refer to an existing object.

```
TgRequest tgRequest = requestRepository.findByIdRequest(1); //Request already exists
Long idPerson = 1; //Person already exists on db, with id = 1,

TgPerson tgPerson = personRepository.getOne(idPerson);

TgRequestPerson tgRequestPerson = new TgRequestPerson();
TgRequestPersonKey tgRequestPersonKey = new TgRequestPersonKey();
tgRequestPersonKey.setIdRequest(tgRequest.getIdRequest());
tgRequestPersonKey.setIdPerson(idPerson);
tgRequest.addTgRequestPerson(tgRequestPerson);
tgPerson.addTgRequestPerson(tgRequestPerson);
tgRequestPerson.setIdRequestPerson(tgRequestPersonKey);


requestRepository.save(tgRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks it works, buy why in the update i don't need that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but if you have another problem or question, please create a new stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the object's (tgPerson) ID  is set. Hibernate distinguishes between transient and detached objects and `save` works only with transient objects. If `save` concludes the object is detached (which it will because the ID is set), it will return the "detached object passed to persist" error. You can find more details [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html) and [here](http://javapeople.blogspot.com/2008/02/transientpersistent-or-detached.html).

However, this only applies if you have specified the primary key to be auto-generated: if the field is configured to always be set manually, then your code works.

So you need to delete those annotations

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TG_PERSON", sequenceName = "S_TG_PERSON", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "TG_PERSON")
```

or call saveOrUpdate method

Comment: i'm using JpaRepository and it doesn't have saveOrUpdate. Actually person also can be saved independently thats why a person already exists and thats why it need the generator.